# Sqlite Date column retrieving error

Tags: android, sqlite, date, datetime, date-format

I am using database operations in Android. There is a table named `"RECORDS"` and it has one column `RECORD_DATE` as `DATE` datatype in my database.
I insert the date data into table using yyyy-MM-dd format.

Now my problem is , I want to retrieve the records data for a particular month only.

```
SELECT aet.RECORD_ID , aet.RECORD_DATE , aet.RECORD_TYPE , aet.RECORD_INFO FROM
RECORDS aet WHERE strftime('%m', aet.RECORD_DATE) = '03'
```

where 03 is a month number taken from user.

This query is returning 0 rows , can anyone help me in this problem?

table data image : 
[TABLE DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAYaV.png)

The android code :

```
public ArrayList<RecordsModel> getRecordsData(int selectedMonth) {

    ArrayList<RecordsModel> arrayListRecordsModel = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        String selectQuery = "SELECT aet.RECORD_ID , aet.RECORD_DATE , aet.RECORD_TYPE  aet.RECORD_INFO FROM RECORDS aet WHERE strftime('%m',  aet.RECORD_DATE ) = ' "+(selectedMonth+1)+" ' ";

        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                model = new RecordsModel();

                model.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                model.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
                model.setType(cursor.getString(2));
                model.setInfo(cursor.getString(3));

                arrayListRecordsModel.add(model);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        db.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return arrayListRecordsModel;

}
```

Comment: I think, the month 03 has no record in the database.

Comment: @TamilSelvanC : there are 20 records in the db.
even if i try to get data with any other number from 0-12 i do not get any rows or data.

Comment: show the screenshot of the sql command `SELECT * FROM
RECORDS`

Comment: @TamilSelvanC : added the image.

Comment: Try simple query first like select * from RECORDS. If it is working then add where condition.

Comment: @user320676 : the image i have shared is about simple select query only. 
please check the table data image.

Comment: yes my friend it is very simple query. It happens sometime that query dont run due to wrong spelling. Try the query in sqlite-manager if it works fine then you can use it into your android code.

Comment: @user320676 : the extra software i am using is db broweser for sqlite. in both android and in this browser it is not working. 
I need more suggestions please.

Comment: show the code in android

Comment: @TamilSelvanC : android code is not an issue, 
the retrieving of the necesary data from the database by the query is the main problem , and the solution i am looking for. 
please suggest me more things to do on the db. i appreciate the help.

Comment: @JavaEnthusias I checked your query by  creating a test table and it is working for me with no issue.

Comment: @JavaEnthusias I have created a database using [SQLite Studio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt) and created a table just like yours. I put a few records and copied and pasted your query and it just worked. So it has no problem. You might need to share more details on how you are executing it in Android.

Comment: I have added the code guys , please check it. if i remove the strftime code it will show all the rows in the table, hence have the doubt that the error is in strftime code only but unable to analyse what exactly it is.

Comment: The issue is `' "+(selectedMonth+1)+" '` . It search as `strftime('%m',  aet.RECORD_DATE ) = ' 02 '` not as `strftime('%m',  aet.RECORD_DATE ) = '02'`

Comment: strftime funtion is perfect, no issue in this. What is the datatype of your RECORD_DATE column? Is it DATETIME?

Comment: @JavaEnthusias see the answer

Comment: @user320676 : the datatype is DATE only.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is space in both side of the selected Month input

```
strftime('%m',  aet.RECORD_DATE ) = ' "+(selectedMonth+1)+" ' ";
                                     ^                     ^
```

When you search a selected month as 03 and it search as
`strftime('%m', aet.RECORD_DATE) = ' 03 '`  so it return no result

**Rewrite a code as**

```
strftime('%m',  aet.RECORD_DATE ) = '"+(selectedMonth+1)+"'";
```

Comment: Hi. 
Applied the changes still did not get the results.

Comment: echo the String selectQuery

Comment: I think 02 + 1 return 3 not 03, may be this cause the issue

Comment: i tried to execute the hardcoded query with 03,04,05.
the selectQuery is what i have written in the problem above.
i have spent more than 10 hours on this still i am not be able to solve this , i dont understand whats the matter here.